# how to calculate percentage in shell

Tags: linux, shell, math, awk, percentage

I would like to calculate percentage in shell. But I can't do it. My script is

```
#!/bin/bash
#n1=$(wc -l < input.txt) #input.txt is a text file with 10000 lines
n1=10000
n2=$(awk '{printf "%.2f", $n1*0.05/100}')
echo 0.05% of $n1 is  $n2
```

It is neither showing any value nor *terminating* when executing this script.

Comment: Why can't you? Is an error stopping you? What's impeding you?

Comment: It is not terminating..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use shell variables in awk script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19075671/how-to-use-shell-variables-in-awk-script)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`awk` will give you an *n1 illegal field name* if you do that, as it's inside single quotes.
Also, to avoid `awk` keep reading stdin you should pass `/dev/null` as file. Then:

```
n2=$(awk -v n1="$n1" 'BEGIN {printf "%.2f", n1*0.05/100}' /dev/null)
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than start a new process to count the records in the file and then passing that to `awk`, I would suggest you let `awk` count the records itself which it does anyway in the variable `NR`. So, your entire script would become:

```
percentage=$(awk 'END{print NR*0.05/100}' input.txt)
```